# What am I missing in my python function? (Beginner)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Write a function named guess_number that receives 1 numeric parameter. It asks the user for a number between 1 and 10 until the user guesses the number in the parameter. It returns the number of times the user guessed.

Here is my code so far, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. It stalls at the input stage.

```
def guess_number(x):
    count = 0
    a = input('Guess my number between 1 and 10')
    while a!= x:
        count += 1
    else:
        count += 1
        return count
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not a correct use of the (obscure but awesome) while-else loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems. First off, your `input` needs to be inside the loop, or else it only gets asked once. So you want this:

```
def guess_number(x):
    count = 0
    while int(raw_input('Guess my number between 1 and 10')) != x:
        count += 1
    else:
        count += 1
        return count
```

Note the (very important!) use of `int(raw_input(...))` instead of just `input`! Allowing your user to execute arbitrary code in your function is a terrible terrible idea, which is why they changed `input`'s behavior in Python 3 to do what `raw_input` does in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You're only asking the user for input once.

Once you enter the while loop, the user is never prompted to enter a new guess. This means the value of `a` never changes, and so you're stuck in the loop forever.

Try including an additional `input` statement:

```
def guess_number(x):
    count = 0
    a = input('Guess my number between 1 and 10')
    while a != x:
        count += 1
        a = input('Guess again!')
    else:
        count += 1
        return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
def guess_number(x):
    count = 1
    a = input('Guess my number between 1 and 10')
    while a != x:
        count += 1
        a = input('Guess my number between 1 and 10')
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program gets stuck at this point:

```
while a!= x:
        count += 1
```

Say x is 5 and a is 3.
In this case, a!=x will evaluate to True, you will enter the loop, and count will be incremented, but you will never leave the while loop because a will always be different from x.

This code should do it:

```
def guess_number(x):
    count = 1
    while True:
        a = input('Guess my number between 1 and 10')
        if a != x:
            count += 1
        else:
            return count
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to moving the `input` inside the `while` loop, unless you intend to pass `x` in as a string, you'll also need to convert `a` in to an `int` before doing the comparison.

```
def guess_number(x):
    count = 0
    while int(input('Guess a number.')) != x:
        count += 1
    return count
```

On a stylistic note, you shouldn't bake the range (1 to 10) in the prompt unless the function actually restricts the range of numbers that can be picked from; `x` can be anything.  I know the question gives specific requirements, but you should question requirements that have bad design implications.

Answer (score 0):

```
def guess_number(x):
    count = 0
    while True:
        a = input('Guess my number between 1 and 10')
        if a!= x:
            count += 1
        else:
            count += 1
            return count
```